# X, Z independent binary random variables and $P(X=1)=p$ and $ P(Z=1)=1/2$ Let R.V $Y = X \oplus Z $

Tags: probability, probability-theory

X, Z independent binary random variables and  $$P(X=1)=p\\ P(Z=1)=1/2$$  Let R.V $Y = X \oplus Z$  where $\oplus$ refers to XOR

We see that $P(Y=1)=P(X=1\land Z=0) + P(X=0\land Z=1)=1/2$

We also see that $P(Y=0)=P(X=1\land Z=1) + P(X=0\land Z=0)=1/2$

Is it safe to assume that X and Y are independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably show $P(X,Y) = P(X)P(Y)$ directly if you want to show independence, but you have basically done that here.